# Passing a variable to a scalar function in SQL2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, t-sql, variables

I have a scalar function that looks up the current date (based on GETDATE()) in a table and returns a single value.  The function accept three parameters: {MonthOffset}, {return_field}, and {CompanyId}.  The {return field} is a VARCHAR(2) value that specifies which column value is to be returned - i.e. 'E' for ending_date, 'B' for beginning_date, ...

If I call the function as:

```
SELECT [dbo].[HCS_fn_FiscalPeriodYear](-1, 'B', 'ABCDEF')
```

I get a proper return of the beginning_date.

If I call the function as :

```
DECLARE @CompanyID VARCHAR(12)
SET @CompanyID = 'ABCDEF'
SELECT [dbo].[HCS_fn_FiscalPeriodYear](-1, 'B', '@CompanyID')
```

I get a return value from the function of 0 that is the error trap value in the function.

Why am I ***NOT*** able to pass the variable value to the function and get a proper return?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Variables do not need to be encased in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an issue with the variable being placed in single quotes so that the function is really getting a string of '@CompanyID' instead of 'ABCDEF'.

Comment: The single quotes around the variable was exactly the problem.  The quotes were an artifact from testing before using the variable.  It is working fine now.  Sometimes it's the most obvious that we can't see!  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Putting something in single quotes makes it a string. This is how you should pass your parameter

```
DECLARE @CompanyID VARCHAR(12)
SET @CompanyID = 'ABCDEF'

SELECT [dbo].[HCS_fn_FiscalPeriodYear](-1, 'B', @CompanyID)
```